# Unity: Nav agent not attached to character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, uinavigationcontroller, navagent

I have a problem with my character being animated but not moving with the nav agent. I'm using root motion.

please find below image for ref.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you attach a navmesh agent to it?

Comment: Nav agent is attached but when I press play the nav agent move and the character stay

Comment: can post any code, the inspector of the character that moves and the character that doesn't and any other detail

Comment: https://files.fm/u/ddnnf58fs this link shows all script that I have

Comment: is your model and the gameobject that has the nav mesh agent the same?

Comment: Yes. see the post I update it. the RigidBody is set as Kinematic